# dynamic variable in base.html - Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

i have a base.html which includes some user profile data which are e-mail , web-site etc.

i need to extend this base.html to my index.html. i can show those data in index.html. because in index page's view i have username paramater [ also in url's ].

how can i handle this ? here is my objects.get code in index view :

```
def user_index(username,request):
    user = Profile.objects.filter(owner__username=username)
    .....
```

and my related url part :

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$',view='user_index', name='user_index'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

> index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}
```

and in

> base.html

```
<doctype ...>
...

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}

...
```

Here, the index.html would extend (inherit) from base.html, and render the contents in `{% block content %}`